# Displaying Posts in Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following code to display my posts in two rows of three columns: 
I am using Bootstrap 3 and have not altered any css that would affect the columns.

```
<?php   
            $query_recents = new WP_Query ( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged ) );

            if ( $query_recents->have_posts() ):
        ?>
        <div class="recent-posts row">  
            <?php while ( $query_recents->have_posts() ) : $query_recents->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_format()); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>  
        <?php endif; ?>
```

this works for the most part except on the second row the first post is shoved down as seen on the image.

could anyone offer advice on how to correct this? 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please inspect CSS and provide some more details..

Comment: Ive prevented from displaying just the excerpt and now it aligns. havent a clue why. - not sure which css to show, col-4-sm and row are pretty standard in Bootstrap, Ive not added any of my own css. recent-posts doesn't have any styles defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply the Responsive column resets, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets and [Bootstrap 3.0:responsive column resets section of the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172397/bootstrap-3-0responsive-column-resets-section-of-the-documentation/19176418)

In your case try:

```
<div class="recent-posts row">  
            <?php 
            $i=0;
            while ( $query_recents->have_posts() ) : $query_recents->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_format()); ?>
                </div>
            <?php 

            if($i++%3==2) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>';
            endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: its always the little things  - occured to me that i hadnt put a clear on them - I had used <div class="clear" at the bottom, like i do in other sites not using bootstrap and I had forgotten to declare a value for clear in css. - DOH!