# Bootstrap 3 - style a site with 3 columns per row on medium & large devices and two columns on small

Tags: less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to style a site with 3 columns of info per row on medium & large devices, just two columns on small devices and one on mobile.

// This is the less I used:

```
.site_info_box_group {
    .make-row();
    .site_info_box {
        .make-sm-column(6);
        .make-md-column(4);
}
```

The problem is I have to use different markup for the different layouts. 
Is it possible to do this sort of design using less. My feeling is that it 
would work best if I put all the #site_info_box's into a single .site_info_box_group 
and then styled every nth div to force it on to a new line - but I'm not sure how to 
get this to work.

I have considered a javascript solution, but I want to understand if this is possible using pure less.

For three columns I'd need this markup

```
<div class="site_info_box_group">
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
<div>

<div class="site_info_box_group">
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
<div>
```

... etc

But for two columns I'd need this markup:

```
<div class="site_info_box_group">
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
<div>

<div class="site_info_box_group">
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
<div>

<div class="site_info_box_group">
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
    <div class="site_info_box"> ... some markup here... </div>
<div>
```

... etc

Comment: I've sort of solved the issue by adding everything to the same row and giving a minimum height to my site_info_box. However this breaks if some content pushes the height beyond the minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix your problem you will need to add all your columns in the same row. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">2</div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">4</div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">6</div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">8</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

See also: [Bootstrap 3.0:responsive column resets section of the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172397/bootstrap-3-0responsive-column-resets-section-of-the-documentation/19176418) <strike>i your case you seems to don't need a clearfix</strike>
When the height of your columns varies you will have to use the [#grid-responsive-resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="height:50px;">2</div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">3</div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">4</div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">6</div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">8</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! A note for anyone trying to implement this with a dynamic number of "cell" divs, calculating the modulus of the current iteration of 3 and 2 will allow you to output the clearfix divs at the right positions. =]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596547/bass-jobsen .
 This is the less I used to make this solution work for me:

```
.site_info_box_group {
    .make-row();
    .site_info_box {
        .make-sm-column(6);
        .make-md-column(4);
    }
    .colsplit2{
        .clearfix;
        .visible-sm;
    }
    .colsplit3{
        .clearfix;
        .visible-md;
        .visible-lg;
    }
}
```

and this is the (simplified) code I used to draw the divs

```
<div class = "site_info_box_group">
<?php
    function draw_div($content){
        static $count=0;
        print "<div class='site_info_box'>{$content}</div>";

        $class ="";
        if (0 == (($count+1) % 2)) {
            $class .= " colsplit2 ";
        };

        if (0 == (($count+1) % 3)){
            $class .= " colsplit3 ";
        };

        if (!empty($class)){
            print "<div class='{$class}'></div>";
        }
        $count++;
    }
    foreach ($mycontent as $content){
        draw_div($content);
    }
?>
</div>
```